# Format ffmpeg command to extract the full klv for an mpg/ts file

Tags: python, unix, ffmpeg, mpeg, transport-stream

I am extracting the [KLV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KLV) data from an mpg file using [klvdata](https://github.com/paretech/klvdata) and ffmpeg.

Following the readme, I have downloaded the sample "Day Flight.mpg" video file that contains KLV data.  Running the quick start command works (I get the exact same result as the [readme example](https://github.com/paretech/klvdata#quick-start) for the first 6 frames.)

However, for the life of me I don't know how I can extract the KLV data for the *entire* video file.

As an experiment, I tried creating the KLV data file from an offset start:

```
ffmpeg -ss 5 -i Day\ Flight.mpg -map data-re -codec copy -f data - > out.klv
```

and when I run it through my code with different start times (5, 25, etc.) I do get different results.

This (to me) would suggest that the mpg file *does* contain KLV data throughout, but I can only access 6 frames at a time.

I would expect to be able to run an ffmpeg command to output the **full** KLV data.  I need help formatting my ffmpeg command to properly provide all the data.

To replicate, download the "Day Flight.mpg" file from the [klvdata project page](https://github.com/paretech/klvdata) and run the command I posted above.  You will note it is less than a page long.  It should be many, many pages long.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: The entire KLV stream looks to have only 6 packets.

Comment: @gyan Thank you for your comment. Could you explain how you came to that conclusion? As I mentioned in the question, by offsetting the start time I am able to produce more than 6 unique packets, so that doesn't seem clear to me.

Comment: Run `ffmpeg -v 0 -ss X -i "Day Flight.mpg" -map 0:1 -c copy -f framecrc -` and check the CRC values, starting with X=0. I only get 6 unique values.

Comment: @Gyan Thanks for providing more detail.  I was definitely misinterpreting the output the first time and now I see that yes, you are correct!  Thanks for the command that helped clarify that for me.